# Setting constraint for two unique fields in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I'm new to postgres. I wonder, what is a PostgreSQL way to set a constraint for a couple of unique values (so that each pair would be unique). Should I create an `INDEX` for `bar` and `baz` fields?

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX foo ON table_name(bar, baz);
```

If not, what is a right way to do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you are already thinking of: **create a unique constraint on both fields**. This way, a **unique index** will be created behind the scenes, and you will get the behavior you need. Plus, that information can be picked up by `information_schema` to do some metadata inferring if necessary on the fact that both need to be unique. I would recommend this option. You can also use triggers for this, but a **unique constraint** is way better for this specific requirement.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, creating a trigger for that is a bit harsh

Comment: It's better to use a `UNIQUE` constraint. That'll create a unique index behind the scenes, but unlike creating a unique index directly it's visible as metadata in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and can be used by tools. Try `ALTER TABLE tname ADD CONSTRAINT bar_baz_unique UNIQUE(bar,baz);` or in your original table definition just add an extra line `CONSTRAINT bar_baz_unique UNIQUE(bar,baz);`.

Comment: @CraigRinger Too bad I didn't see that because my name isn't mentioned in your message. I think its really a more obvious syntax and a better way to do that, you should write an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @JohnDoe Should've at-mentioned, yeah. Still, so long as people who see Pablo's answer see it, that's fine. Better still if he edits his answer to include the better style.

Comment: Thanks @CraigRinger: totally agree with you.

Answer (score 4):

If each field needs to be unique unto itself, then create unique indexes on each field.  If they need to be unique in combination only, then create a single unique index across both fields.

Don't forget to set each field NOT NULL if it should be.  NULLs are never unique, so something like this can happen:

```
create table test (a int, b int);
create unique index test_a_b_unq on test (a,b);
insert into test values (NULL,1);
insert into test values (NULL,1);
```

and get no error.  Because the two NULLs are not unique.